# Ajax Posts Empty Name - Fixed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have fallowing code parse json files from `.json` file and works well. when i give it name and trying to post from form data gives me empty post data.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="jewels" ></div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON( "include/settings/guild_bank_jevels.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
   items.push( "<option  name='jewel_name' value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>" );
  });

  $( "<select/>", {

    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "#jewels" );
});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

UPDATE Fixed

Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON( "include/settings/guild_bank_jevels.json", function( data ) {
    var items = [];

    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      items.push( "<option   value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>" );
    });

    $("#jewels").html(items);
    });
     </script>
```

HTML Part:

```
<select id="jewels" name="jewel_name"> 
</select>
```

Comment: The first code work like you can see in my answer you have just to remove the extra double quotes.

Comment: And you shouldn't add the solution in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have some extra double quotes `"` in the following line :

```
items.push( "<option  name="'jewel_name'" value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>" );
___________________________^____________^
```

Please try to replace it by :

```
items.push( "<option  name='jewel_name' value='" + key + "'>" + val + key + "</option>" );
```

---

### Snippet

```js
var items = [];
var data={'first_key': 'first_val', 'second_key': 'second_val'};
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
  items.push( "<option  name='jewel_name' value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>" );
});

$( "<select/>", {

  html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "#jewels" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jewels" ></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i can get list and make select list success. but still same it doesnt posts name tagged data from parsed list.

Comment: Please try to describe more clearly what it the main problem.

Comment: You're welcome, but it's not correct to push answer inside question you should post an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your select doesn't have a name or id. Inputs need to have one of these for forms to post their value.

```
$( "<select/>", {
    id='some_id',
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "#jewels" );
```

Comment: well when i try to change it all list gone. i thing i need another way to load list and put name. any ideas?